# data manipulation for each row with conditions in data.table

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have a data table "DT". Now, I would like to make columns A1:B3 equal to the previous row and then update the values according to conditions, the entire first row is given. There is no pattern in each column.

```
       ID title action  value   A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
 1:    1   A3     1       15    7   9   15  45  20  62 
 2:    2   A1     0       22    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
 3:    3   B2     1       92    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
 4:    4   A2     0       17    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
 5:    8   B1     1       55    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 6:    6   B3     1       37    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
 7:   12   B2     0       16    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 8:    8   A1     1       35    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 9:    9   B3     1       13    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

from row 2 to row 9, i want to for each row j, i want to

```
 DT[j, A1:B3]=DT[j-1, A1:B3]
```

Then update A1:B3 according to the values in each corresponding row.The element to update is from the corresponding column called "title."

For row 2, from `A1` to `B3`, copy `7   9   15  45  20  62` from the previous row, then change `A1` (`DT[2, title]` gives this information), `DT[2, action]` is `0`, so we insert `22` to be `A1`, and move `7` to `A2`, move `9` to `A3`, delete the original `A3`. `DT[2, A1:B3]` becomes `22   7   9  45  20  62` (column names starting with `'A'` can not be pushed to `'B'`.). If `DT[2, action]` is `1`, then just simply replace.

After processing, the desired output should look like:

```
       ID title action  value   A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
 1:    1   A3     1       15    7    9  15  45  20  62 
 2:    2   A1     0       22    22   7   9  45  20  62 
 3:    3   B2     1       92    22   7   9  45  92  62  
 4:    4   A2     0       17    22   17  7  45  92  62  
 5:    8   B1     1       55    22   17  7  55  92  62
 6:    6   B3     1       37    22   17  7  55  92  37 
 7:   12   B2     0       16    22   17  7  55  16  92
 8:    8   A1     1       35    35   17  7  55  16  92
 9:    9   B3     1       13    35   17  7  55  16  13
```

I am using a loop now to do it, but it is extremely slow, and it only works when `action == 1`, when `action == 0`, I am not sure how to squeeze in the new value.

```
for (j in 2:nrow(DT)){
  DT[j, A1:B3] <- DT[j-1, A1:B3]
  if(DT$action[j] == 1) { 
    position <- which.first(colnames(DT) == DT$title[j], use.names = TRUE)
    DT[j,position] <- DT$value[j]
  }  
}
```

when  `action` is `1`, it is straightforward, when `action` is `0`, it may be confusing.

Feel free to leave me comments or refer to the desired output. I will be glad to do more explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one for several reasons:

1. iteratively copy values from one row to the next, thereby applying different manipulations,
2. one of the manipulations is to insert a value and shift the remaining values across columns.

The approach below reshapes the data from wide to long format due to (2.) which enables us to use the `append()` function to insert values *column-wise*. And it uses a `for` loop due to (1.) and the `set()` function to update by reference, i.e., without copying the whole data object:

```
# append row number, then reshape from wide to long format 
long <- melt(DT[, rn := .I], measure.vars = patterns("^[AB]\\d"), value.name = "val")[order(rn)]
for (i in seq_len(nrow(DT) - 1L) + 1L){
  # copy the row values from previous row
  set(long, long[rn == i, which = TRUE], "val", long[rn == (i - 1L), .(val)])
  # update values depending on action indicator
  if (long[rn == i, first(action) == 1]) {
    # replace selected value
    idx <- long[rn == i & variable == title, which = TRUE]
    set(long, idx, "val", long[idx[1L], value])
  } else {
    # insert selected value
    pat <- paste0("^", long[rn == i, stringi::stri_sub(first(title), 1L, 1L)])
    idx <- long[rn == i & variable %like% pat, which = TRUE]
    set(long, idx, "val", 
        head( # drop last element after insert
          append(long[idx, val], long[idx[1L], value], 
                 after = long[idx[1L], as.integer(stringi::stri_sub(title, 2L)) - 1L]), 
          -1L))
  }
}
# reshape back to wide format
dcast(long, rn + ... ~ variable, value.var = "val")[, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>    ID title action value A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
> 1:  1    A3      1    15  7  9 15 45 20 62
> 2:  2    A1      0    22 22  7  9 45 20 62
> 3:  3    B2      1    92 22  7  9 45 92 62
> 4:  4    A2      0    17 22 17  7 45 92 62
> 5:  8    B1      1    55 22 17  7 55 92 62
> 6:  6    B3      1    37 22 17  7 55 92 37
> 7: 12    B2      0    16 22 17  7 55 16 92
> 8:  8    A1      1    35 35 17  7 55 16 92
> 9:  9    B3      1    13 35 17  7 55 16 13
> ```